# Refresh JStree data

Tags: javascript, jstree

I am using a `JSTree` and for this, I load the data, but in some situations, I need to reload the data with another database filter that will arrive. But how can I add the data to the `JSTRee`, it is keeping the old data always.

I tried in in the `complete` as following:

```
complete: function() { a $('#mytree').jstree(true).refresh();
```

But no change.

```
function loadTreeContent(bindTo)
{
    $.ajax({
        type: 'get',
        url: bindTo,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {
            $('#mytree').jstree({
                'core' : {
                    'data' : data
                },
                'checkbox' : {
                    "keep_selected_style" : false
                },
                "plugins" : [ 'checkbox', 'contextmenu', 'state'],
                'checkbox': {
                    three_state : true,
                    whole_node : false,
                    tie_selection : false
                },
                'contextmenu': {
                    'items': function ($node) {
                        var tree = $('#mytree').jstree(true);
                        if($node.a_attr.type === 'test')
                            return getTestContextMenu($node, tree);
                    }
                }
            });
        },
        complete: function() {
            // This function will be triggered always, 
            // when ajax request is completed, even it fails/returns other status code
            console.log("complete");
        },
        error: function() {
            // This will be triggered when ajax request fail.
            console.log("Error");
        }
    });
};
```

Comment: One way is to destroy and reinitialize jstree or you can use `redraw(true)`.

Answer (score 1):

Try `redraw` instead of `refresh`:

```
complete: function() { a $('#mytree').jstree(true).redraw(true);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$(".jstree").jstree(true).refresh(true, true);
```

If you use state (checked and selected) plugin in jstree, then the refresh method become complicated.
refresh method has two parameters

```
refresh(skip_loading, forget_state)
```

By default:

1. skip_loading: {Boolean} skip_loading an option to skip showing the loading indicator
2. forget_state: {Mixed} forget_state if set to `true` state will not be reapplied, if set to a function (receiving the current state as argument) the result of that. So, by default, it you don't give any value, it will apply existing state before refresh.

So, my case was that I need to clean up my previous state, then I need to call

```
$(".jstree").jstree(true).refresh(true, true);
```

See https://github.com/vakata/jstree/issues/2112#issuecomment-421551095
and source code: https://github.com/vakata/jstree/blob/master/src/jstree.js